Is dynamics between place cell spike & local theta activity comparable to principal/interneuron spikes and fast field oscillations (ripple events)?
Place cell spikes (pyramidal & granule) are phase-locked with local theta activity. They peak at the trough of theta.
Neuronal spikes (principal and interneuron) also seem to be influenced by the phase of the fast field oscillation (ripple events). For instance, in Fig 2 of the paper linked below, the large central wave (4th wave) of the ripple event sees the most no. of pyramidal unit firings. The paper also mentions how the firing of interneurons and pyramidal cells are phase-locked since interneurons's avg peak firing are time-shifted by 1/2 cycles in relation to the peak of pyramidal cell firing.
So can we say that the fast-field oscillation (ripple event) influences the firing of the pyramidal cells the same way local theta influences the firing of place cells?
High-Frequency Network Oscillation in the Hippocampus

Somewhat related Q&A: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/20075/why-do-brains-oscillate-within-specific-frequency-ranges/20086#20086 Also maybe: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/26610/neural-oscillations-and-activity-patterns/26611#26611 I may come to write a more targeted answer for you here, but I think you'll be helped by stepping back and thinking about what an "oscillation" is in the brain: what it represents, physically. I think you're thinking about them far too abstractly, you should think about them as related to a system of many neurons.

@BryanKrause In context of theta, during exploratory activities, neuronal population of hippocampus exhibit group oscillatory behavior associated with LFP range 4-12 Hz. This theta activity, the way I understand it, sets the temporal stage for the participating place cell spike. I have some questions in this front too - https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/30567/how-do-you-estimate-distance-between-two-place-fields-based-on-compression-rule
I wanted to know if Ripple events are emergent phenomena similar to theta that plays role in temporal co-ordination of individual neuronal spike

@BryanKrause My impression is that both the subthreshold membrane potential oscillations and the discharge of pyramidal/interneuron cells give rise to the dynamics of theta rhythm and the phase-locked place cell spike activity. So there are 2 components: action potential and subthreshold membrane gradient potential. Is this also what's happening during ripple event, only it exhibits the most synchronous large population burst in comparison to all brain events?
